# Copying structure members

Tags: c, struct

I am more confused with structures. There are many ways to copy a structure.

```
struct complex
{
   int real;
   int imaginary;
};

Assume c1 is complex structure variable. c2 is pointer of complex type.
```

One way is simply assign one structure to another. `c1=*c2`. 
I tried it. It works fine. But c2 will give the address of first element of structure complex. Then how the entire structure will be copied? Am i more confused with pointers?

Another way is using `memcpy`  `memcpy(&c1,c2,sizeof(struct complex))`.

My doubt is on member-wise structure copying.
      `memcpy(&c1.real, &c2->real, sizeof(struct complex))`

I read that the above method is not safe. Because it won't work if we change the order of structure members. Nobody explained how is not safe? It confuses me because both variables are same structures , i am specifying what i want to copy [real in this case]. Then why is it not safe? could anybody please explain it?

Comment: `memcpy(&c1.real, &c2->real, sizeof(struct complex))` - you should see that this is very problematic. The problem isn't that this is not safe, it's plain wrong. How much and where to are you copying? It might work, but it does not have to by any means. I also don't understand what you really ask about.

Comment: In the line where are u copying the member wise structure copying ... you are copying member `&c1.real` but giving the size of structure ... just give size of variable .....then try it..!!!

Comment: Using memcpy is unnecessary for what you are doing. Just use assignments. That second memcpy is bad because you are trying to copy sizeof(struct complex) bytes when it should be sizeof(int) bytes. If you put real after complex it will start writing past the end of the structs memory since it will still write (presumably) 8 bytes. What you have now will copy the entire struct but it is an obscure way of doing it. If you do that with any other member than the first, memcpy will write (or at least try to) something outside the struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course the only sane way is to use assignment:

```
c1 = *c2;
```

It's true that the actual numerical value of `c2`, a pointer to a structure, is the same as the address of the first member. But that't **doesn't matter**. The *types* of the values involved in the assignment are both `struct complex`, that is what the assignment is working with and all needed bits will be copied.

Do **not** use `memcpy()` to copy a structure, there is absolutely no point! It can in fact be a net negative, since th structure can contain padding which the assignment operator (being an operator, whose code generation is controlled by the compiler for this specific usage) can deal with and skip over, saving time. The function `memcpy()` has no idea of the padding of course, it's job is to copy all bytes and that's what it will do.

Also, of course, do *not* use `memcpy()` to copy individual `int`-sized members. That's just ... not right, don't do that.

Also, the assignment is higher-level, thus more abstract, and thus more compact and communicates more efficiently.

Of course, if the structure contains pointers of its own (yours does not) you must take care to do a [deep copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy), and allocate new instances of the pointed-to data and copying that too. That has nothing to do with how the actual copying is done though.

Use `struct` assignment. Always.

Comment: @mjs Yes, of course. Copying the structure itself with `memcpy()` doesn't change that, it's no better.

Answer (score 0):

I you change the order of fields in the following way:

```
struct complex
{
    int imaginary;
    int real;
);
```

Then `memcpy(&c1.real, &c2->real, sizeof(struct complex))` will try to copy fields **starting** from `real` and as the number of bytes you are trying to copy is the size of the **whole** structure it will access memory **after** the structure thus causing invalid memory access in some cases and in some cases it will does not produce any error. But the result of this operation is not what you expected. For ones, it will not copy the field `imaginary`.

In case of you need to copy part of the structure - this is the way to do it:

```
memcpy(&c1.real, &c2->real, sizeof(struct complex) - offsetof(struct complex, real));
```

Where `offsetof` is a macro declared like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order of structure members has no effect in this case. Struct fields are explicitly stated, as you mentioned.

When things get more complex, it's easier to make mistakes. As you did:

```
memcpy(&c1.real, &c2->real, sizeof(struct complex));
```

It should have been:

```
memcpy(&c1.real, &c2->real, sizeof(c1.real));
```

Simpler is better:

```
c1.real = c2->real;
```

By using `memcpy` there is also another problem; you lose type safety. Sometimes you want that, but not usually when working with 2 entities with same data type.

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy(&c1.real, &c2->real, sizeof(struct complex))` is very strange, since bots types are atomic, there is no need for that kind of copying. Also `sizeof(struct complex)` is wrong, because it should have been `sizeof(int)` (which is only 1/2 size of the whole structure) 
Simple assignment is enough:

```
c1.real = c2->real;
```